# Annotation Inheritance in jersey

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, jersey-2.0

I'm creating some resource class with same form so a good idea is use DRY and use inheritance.
So I've create a RootResource class and put some methods there. I want to annotate them and then implement them in subclass but it doesn't work! Here is a sample code:

```
public abstract class RootResource {
  @GET
  @Path("/{id: .*}")
  public abstract String getInfo(String uid);
}

@Path("/user")
public class UserResource extends RootResource{
  public String getInfo(@PathParam("id") String uid) {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
  }
}
```

I'm using jersey 2.6.
Any Idea?
Thanks.

Comment: This example doesn't even compile.. the return type of String isn't FullDTO...  Can you try putting the path param in the method signature on the abstract class?  Did you try interface?

Comment: Yes, I've correct it in my question. I need RootResource be an abstract class. Also adding PathParam to RootResource.getInfo signature doesn't help.

Answer (score 7):

I've been through the same issue while using Jersey. The [Java EE standard for JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-edr3-spec/jaxrs-2_0-edr3-spec.pdf) states the following:

> **3.6 Annotation Inheritance**
>
> JAX-RS annotations MAY be used on the methods and method parameters of a > super-class or an implemented
>   interface. Such annotations are inherited by a corresponding sub-class
>   or implementation class method provided that method and its parameters
>   do not have any JAX-RS annotations of its own. Annotations on a
>   super-class take precedence over those on an implemented interface.
>   The precedence over conflicting annotations defined in multiple
>   implemented interfaces is implementation specific.
>
> **If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on the super class or interface method are
>   ignored**.

While Jersey as the reference implementation is very strict with this statement, [Resteasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) implementation is more lenient and did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to specify the path over the class since it's the root resource class so the it will get where to look at the class loading and not for individual overridden methods:

```
    @Path("/account/member/")
    public class RootResource {
             . . .
```

Comment: The root class is an abstract class so I get a `java.lang.InstantiationException` exception.
Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: ah you need to put it on your derived class