# All jersey routes with @PathParam returns 404

Tags: java, rest, jersey, grizzly

I have several **RESTful** services using **Jersey**, running on **Grizzly**. All the routes with `@PathParam` returns `404` error code. Can anybody please guide where to look into?

Working:

```
@GET
@Path("/testget")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response testGet(){
    //working
}
```

Not Working:

```
@GET
@Path("/testpath/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response testPath(@PathParam("id") String id){
    //not working, return 404
}
```

If I remove the path param, it starts working. But I need the path param.

Grizzly code:

```
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.register(TestController.class);

        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URL), resourceConfig, false);
        server.start();
```

Comment: Are you saying that url `.../testget` works, but a url like `.../testpath/abc` doesn't work?

Comment: exactly, thats the problem. I guess, jersey/grizzly can't map testpath/abc to testpath/{id}

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I just created brand new project using instructions from [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/griz_jersey_intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html), then added both your methods to the sample `MyResource` class, making them return "Hello from <methodname>". Both worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, I have found my solution. I am adding it here as someone might be beneficial from this.

**Problem**

I found that, adding the POST and Path on interface method causes the problem. And this happens when there is a @PathParam in method parameter.

*Problematic:*
Interface:

```
@POST
@Path("/test/{id}")
public String testPost(@PathParam("id") String id);
```

Class(base resource is on class level Path annotation):

```
@Override
public String testPost(@PathParam("id") String id){
    return "hello" + id;
}
```

**Solution**

Class:

```
@POST
@Path("/test/{id}")
@Override
public String testPost(@PathParam("id") String id){
    return "hello" + id;
}
```

It does not matter whether I add the POST and Path on interface or not. But those must be added to implementing method. At least this is working for me, I don't know why the annotation in interface is not working. As the J2EE specification says:

> Blockquote
> For consistency with other Java EE specifications, it is recommended to always repeat annotations instead of relying on annotation inheritance.

So, I am adding the annotation in classes.

Comment: You should remove @PathParam from implementation, otherwise all annotations on interface will be ignored.
This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37623021/105668 explains it in more details.